# Where can I post code for others to review?

Tags: support, site-recommendation, scope

In which section of Stack Overflow (or the Stack Exchange network) can I request a code review from my peers, or ask them to tell me what errors might be in my code, or help me to optimize it for performance?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You're in luck! We just so happen to have a site explicitly designed for code reviews.

It's called **Code Review**: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

> This is a collaboratively edited question and answer site for programmers interested in sharing code for peer review. It's 100% free, no registration required.
>
> **What kind of questions can I ask here?**
>
> Code Review - Stack Exchange is for sharing code from projects you are working on for peer review. If you are looking for specific feedback about…
>
> - Code correctness
> - Best practices and design pattern usage in your code
> - Application UI
> - Security issues in a code snippet, etc.
> - The performance of your code
>
> and your question is *not* about …
>
> - Tools, best practices, improving, or conducting code reviews
> - Trouble-shooting, debugging, or understanding code snippets
> - Higher-level architecture and design of software systems
>
> … then you are in the right place!

Comment: why it's not in the below section of the page :(

Comment: @Sourav: Probably because it's still in beta. If you find it useful, please join and participate. If there are enough members who actively participate, it can move out of beta and become a full fledged site!