# Recommended site for free code review\sharing code in SOF

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where can I post code for others to review?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90362/where-can-i-post-code-for-others-to-review)

I want to share a solution I'm working on for two reasons:

1) To get some code review from people.

Are there any sites for free code reviews?

2) to ask an architecture question on Stack Overflow

Is it acceptible to attach a branch?

Comment: You could ask such questions here; but bear in mind that a good code reviewer should have knowledge of all your application's code (and the libraries used), and this knowledge is hard to get to an outsider. This is probably why the community aspects of real free software projects (particularily big ones) is important.

Comment: what about using some software's that do code review

Comment: @refhat, could you recommend such software? I would be very interested.

Comment: would you pls go through 


http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/2927/asp-net-site-architecture-review

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. https://codereview.stackexchange.com/
2. No. You can ask architectural questions though