# Can I request code comments?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where can I post code for others to review?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90362/where-can-i-post-code-for-others-to-review)

I have created a piece of code that I want other peoples feedback on. Can I use Stack Overflow for this, or must questions be have strictly problem solving characteristics?

Answer (score 1):

Stack Overflow is not the right site for such questions.

However, if the code is otherwise working correctly, you can use http://codereview.stackexchange.com Have a look at [their FAQ](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/faq) to see if it fits your needs.