# Which Stack Exchange site is best for code review?

Tags: support, questions, site-recommendation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where can I post code for others to review?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90362/where-can-i-post-code-for-others-to-review)

Which Stack Exchange site is best for code review?

Suppose I have a question like:

> Is the following code a proper solution to <my problem>?

`<Code>`

On which (if any) Stack Exchange site would this question be most appropriately asked? Is it wrong to ask code-review type questions like this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That would be [codereview.stackexchange.com](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

The [FAQ reads](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/faq):

> Code Review - Stack Exchange is for sharing code from projects you are
>   working on for peer review. If you are looking for feedback on a
>   specific working piece of code from your project in the following
>   areas…
>
> - Best practices and design pattern usage
> - Security issues
> - Performance
> - Correctness in unanticipated cases
>
> then you are in the right place!